# Laravel 5 > orderBy difference between up and down votes > pagination

Tags: laravel, pagination, relationship, difference

Assumed I´ve got the following DB setup

**users table**

```
id
name
```

**posts table**

```
id
post
```

**votes table**

```
id
user_id
post_id
vote (1 = up, -1 = down)
```

... and let´s also assume I´ve setup every one-to-many relationship correctly :)

**How do I query the top 5 posts measured by the difference between it´s up and down votes?**

Something like this would be great ...

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('votes', function($query) {
    $query->orderByRaw('sum(\'vote\'), desc');
})->get();
```

... and I`d like to paginate later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now working :)

```
$posts = Post::has('votes')
    ->leftJoin('votes', 'votes.post_id', '=', 'posts.id')
    ->selectRaw('posts.*, sum(votes.vote) as votes_sum')
    ->groupBy('posts.id')
    ->orderBy('votes_sum', 'desc')
    ->paginate(5);
```